# In raft leader election,how live leader response to RequestVote rpc from a candidate?

Tags: raft, leader

i am reading the raft paper.

To the requestvote rpc,

> Receiver implementation:
>   1. Reply false if term < currentTerm (§5.1)
>   2. If votedFor is null or candidateId, and candidate’s log is at
>   least as up-to-date as receiver’s log, grant vote (§5.2, §5.4)

in some situation , candidate's term is equal to leader' currentTerm,so how does the leader response to RequestVote rpc from a  candidate?

Answer (score 4):

Let's pick this apart in more human terms:

1. If the vote is from an older term (`term < currentTerm`), ignore it.
2. If we haven't voted in this term (`votedFor is null`), or if it's a vote for the same candidate we voted for last time in this term (`votedFor == candidateId`), then grant the vote as long as the candidate log is up-to-date.

Remember that leaders vote for themselves in a given term.

That means that for `term == currentTerm`, the leader will have `votedFor` equal to itself. This is not null, so the only way it will grant this vote is if `candidateId` is itself - i.e., it's casting a vote for itself in the current term. In all other cases, it will not grant the vote.

The high-level thing to remember (in fact, the key invariant in all of this) is that a server *never* votes more than once in the same term. Once it has made its vote for a term, it's final. And since a leader votes for itself, when it receives other requests for the same term it won't grant it.